# The class equation of the octahedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry

I know that the class equation of the octahedral group is this:
$$1 + 8 + 6 + 6 + 3$$

I think the $8$ stands for the $8$ vertices, the $6$ could be $6$ faces and $6$ pairs of edges. Then what is the $3$ for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These numbers have nothing to do with the numbers of vertices, faces, or edges, at least not so directly.  The octohedral group has $1$ identity element, which is the sole member of its own conjugacy class.  The group has $8$ three-fold rotations along axes joining two opposite vertices.  It has $6$ two-fold rotations along axes joining the midpoints of two opposite edges. It has $6$ four-fold rotations along axes joining the midpoints of opposite faces.  Finally, it has $3$ two-fold rotations along axes joining the midpoints of opposite faces.

Comment: Thank you, I am clear with first 2 rotations, but the last 2 ones rotate along the same axis, what is the difference?

Comment: Rotating by $90$ degrees or $270$ degrees gives you a four-fold rotation, but rotating by $180$ degrees gives you a two-fold rotation.

Comment: Oh, I see, the left rotate and right rotate of 180 overlapped make a 3. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As described on [the Wikipedia page for the octahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry#Details), the conjugacy classes are

> - identity
> - 6 × rotation by 90° about [an axis with 4-fold symmetry]
> - 8 × rotation by 120° about a [an axis with 3-fold symmetry]
> - 3 × rotation by 180° about a [an axis with 4-fold symmetry]
> - 6 × rotation by 180° about a [an axis with 2-fold symmetry]

Answer (score 1):

Following the Wikipedia list of conjugacy classes given by Zev Chonoles, we obtain:

24 = 1 (identity from the whole **octahedron**) + 8 (rotation by 120° about a **face**, an axis with 3-fold symmetry) + 6 (rotation by 180° about an **edge**, an axis with 2-fold symmetry) + 6 (rotation by 90° about a **vertex**, an axis with 4-fold symmetry) + 3 (rotation by 180° about a **vertex**, an axis with 4-fold symmetry)

This is the exact relation between conjugacy classes and rotations about icosahedron's axes of symmetry

For details see Algebra 2nd edition chapter 7.4 'The Class Equation of the Icosahedral Group' by M. Artin

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The key may be that there are 3 squares in an octahedron, and for each square, a group $G$ isomorphic to $(Z/Z2)^3$, whose order is 8, acts on it. $G$ consists of 3 two-fold rotations and the axes are showed in the picture above.

$24 ＝ 8 × 3$

Comment: Why is that the key?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's not correct, because the $D_4$ is non-abelian, and is not a centralizer, so I'll find another way to describe it

Answer (score 0):

[image]

number every pair of opposite faces, and the octahedral group $O$ acts on the set consisting of 4 numbers, that we could prove $O\cong S_4$

here are the elements

**vertices 6 (π/2)**

```
(1 2 3 4)  (1 3 4 2)  (1 4 2 3)
(1 4 3 2)  (1 2 4 3)  (1 3 2 4)
```

**faces 8 (2π/3)**

```
(1 2 3)  (1 2 4)  (1 3 4)  (2 3 4)
(1 3 2)  (1 4 2)  (1 4 3)  (2 4 3)
```

**edges 6 (π)**

```
(1 2)  (1 3)  (1 4)  (2 3)  (2 4)  (3 4)
```

**vertices 3 (π)**

```
(1 2)(3 4)  (1 3)(2 4)  (1 4)(2 3)
```

**identity 1 (2π)**

```
()
```

Comment: the "vertices 3 (π)" can be thought as ""edges 6 (π)" compounds "edges 6 (π)" except for "identity 1 (2π)""